# System does not start when power is on - 14.04

Tags: 14.04, boot

When I turn on the power of my laptop, it shows the following lines of text and starts to fluctuate. (It has Ubuntu 14.04.)

[image: boot screenshot]

When I press the `esc` key the system starts but the mouse pad doesn't work.

I am stuck and don't know what to do.
If anybody has got any kind of solution please it is acceptable.
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: The image is not clear

Comment: @Arun I can only capture this image because of the fluctuation of screen.

Comment: Try recovey option from grub menu

Comment: Already tried but i can't use recovery mode always

Comment: From the recovery mode screen select dpkg

Comment: what is dpkg means

Comment: When you enter recovery you will see a list of options

Answer (score 0):

## Partial answer... work in progress...

Lets first check your file system for errors.

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`